# php header function don't work

Tags: php, header

when I define the header in a php file as shown below:

```
header("Location: invitadoinicio.php");
```

appears the next message:

> Object not localized!
>
> The requested URL has not been located on this server. The URL of the
>   page you have submitted seems to be wrong or obsolete. Please report
>   the error to the author of that page.
>
> If you believe that this is a server error, please communicate it to
>   the portal administrator. Error 404 localhost Apache / 2.4.25 (Win32)
>   OpenSSL / 1.0.2j PHP / 5.6.30

the view is on this path:

```
view/solucion/invitados/invitadoinicio.php
```

Comment: "Object not localized" seems very specific to your code base, there are four results in google for that phrase.

Comment: @Scuzzy - or poor translation. Looks a lot like the output of a 404, esp since it includes the words Error 404 in the output....

Comment: the function works fine, the location does not exist.

Comment: What is the path of the file where you have your `header()` function?

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be based on using `include()` and similar functions, and the location of where the file is that actually calls the `header()` function.

I would recommend using either strict absolute paths

```
header("location: https://www.example.com/path/to/file.php");
```

or build it using  a variable if your code is running on many domains -

```
header("location: https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/path/to/file.php");
```

or since the HTTP spec was modified a few years ago to allow relative paths, use a host relative path -

```
header("location: /path/to/file.php");
```

By using a truly relative reference - just the file name - you are opening it to ambiguity and the possibility of confusion, especially if the `header()` call is in an included file and the file referencing it is in a different directory path.